# i get this exception in java Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum value of array is : " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum value of array is : " + min);
    }
}
```

When I compile this code it keeps going on until I terminate it and when done so it gives the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: I ran the code from your question and entered integers only and got no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion,that's normal phenomenon,check the api document of [InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html),we can find below description:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved **does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.**

In your code we can see

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = sc.nextInt();
```

So when you terminate it, the input signal can not conver to `int`,thus the exception will thrown.